# Unable to receive call on VoIP number using GoIP 4

Tags: voip, gsm, sms-gateway

I am unable to receive calls from any number to my VoIP number. I am using GoIP 4 (GSM over IP). Device details are following:
Firmware Version:   GS-4.01-96 
Module Version: M35FAR02A01_RSIM
Software Name: EasyPhone

Call In settings:
User No Input Timeout(s):    60
CID Forward Mode:    Use CID as SIP caller ID
CID Prefix:    Null
Channel:    CH1
Call IN via GSM:    Enable
Forwarding to VoIP Number:    3333
Dial Plan: Null
GSM Call Waiting:    Disable
Hunt Group Mode:    Disable
Auto Incoming Call Block:   Enable

In a simple way, my question is how to configure GoIP 4 to receive calls and forward to VoIP number?
Kindly help me to configure it with the right way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Check your GOIP status if the VOIP is showing "Y", If it is, then go to the Call in setting.

Your dial plan should be ";" instead of none, disable your Auto Incoming Call Block, and in your Inbound Route in elastix, let your DID be your extension no.

Call in setting:

- User No Input Timeout(s): 60
- CID Forward Mode: Use CID as SIP caller ID
- CID Prefix: Null
- Channel: CH1
- Call IN via GSM: Enable
- Forwarding to VoIP Number:Ur extension No
- Dial Plan: ;
- GSM Call Waiting: Disable
- Hunt Group Mode: Disable
- Auto Incoming Call Block: disable

Comment: Please don't use text speak in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i've reset my device and try to configure it again. Now the problem is the VoIP status is 'N' and i am unable to make calls.